# Unmet dependencies (python3-distupgrade)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core : Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:18.04.34) but 1:18.04.29 is to be installed
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:18.04.34) but 1:18.04.29 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I'm trying to install an appli with apt-get and i can't cause of this error of python dependencies , i don't find any way here to solve this ... 
can someone help me with this ? thank's a lot !

Comment: You haven't told us your release (it looks like 18.04).  It looks like you need to update your source lists (`sudo apt update`) where do you get any errors?  I'd also check your mirror is up-to-date & maintained; as 18.04.34 is the expected package to get downloaded (not the 18.04.29 your message shows!) https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-distupgrade

Comment: Hey guiverc and thank's for the help, so yes thats 18.04, and i get these errors when i try to install something

Comment: To validate the status of your chosen mirror, refer to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors   (*problems can be expected on any listed as *Last update unknown* as it's too  long ago day-counter overflowed*)

Comment: so if i understood you correctly i should go on your link and select bionic (18.04LTS) (python): manage release upgrades

Comment: I would `sudo apt update` & ensure you get no errors or warnings. I also would look at what mirror you are using; check it on the list I provided, eg. my chosen mirror is listed in a green "Up to date" as to status ..  however if your mirror is red or black - ie. way behind - that could be your problem.  Change mirror if necessary & try again...

Comment: well thank's you karel i just repaired my PPA error for MySQL :)

Comment: Now i'm always trying to fix this python-distupgrade error when i want to install something on my computer

Comment: So i dont know how to upgrade my 18.04.29 to 04.34 if someone have any advices on how to upgrade python-distupgrade with the links that guiverc shared to me ?